# RegExp that begins with 2 specific digits

Tags: regex

I need to make a RegExp that looks for a string that begins with `05`, might be 10 or 11 chars long and might include a hyphen 
I tried to do something like that:

```
([0-9, -]{10,11})
```

But had no idea how to begin it with 05.

Eventually I need to get strings like 0512345678 or 051-2345678.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thy this.

```
(^05[0-9\-\.]{8,12})
```

and example:

https://regex101.com/r/uI1hT8/2

Comment: Sorry it took so long. But it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(05[0-9, -]{8,9})
```

That will fix the first two characters to be "05"